# code doesn't see value of JTextField, despite it displays in the interface

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, gettext, numberformatexception

I want to get int value from the nrZamowieniaJTF (TextField). It is initialized in another window (OknoListaZamowien) by this code:

```
if (e.getSource() == zapiszJB) {
OknoEdycjaZamowienia ob = new OknoEdycjaZamowienia();
ob.setVisible(true);
try {
    nrZamowieniaLista = Integer.parseInt(idJTF.getText());
} catch (NumberFormatException xxx) {
    nrZamowieniaLista = 1;
    idJTF.setText("1");
}

ob.nrZamowieniaJTF.setText(Integer.toString(nrZamowieniaLista));
this.setVisible(false);
}
```

So this is how window looks (as you can see, number 3 is now assigned to nrZamowieniaJTF): 
[window where nrZamowieniaJTF shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCbom.png)

But I'm having an error when I'm trying to get this value to int into another window called OknoEdycjaZamowienia like this:

```
nrZamowieniaJTF = new JTextField();
nrZamowieniaJTF.setBounds(460, 30, 100, 20);
nrZamowieniaJTF.setEditable(false);
getContentPane().add(nrZamowieniaJTF);

int nrZamowienia = Integer.parseInt(nrZamowieniaJTF.getText());
```

That's the error that I'm facing (when I do, the window (on picture) doesn't diplay):

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""   at
java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)     at
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)    at
com.tasia2931.okna.OknoEdycjaZamowienia.<init>(OknoEdycjaZamowienia.java:135)
    at
com.tasia2931.okna.OknoListaZamowien.actionPerformed(OknoListaZamowien.java:125)    at
javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at
javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at
javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at
javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at
javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539)    at
javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)  at
java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)    at
java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)    at
java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)   at
java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)   at
java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)   at
java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
    at
java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)    at
java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)     at
java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)   at
java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)  at
java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)  at
java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)  at
java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)  at
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  at
java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at
java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)   at
java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)  at
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  at
java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)   at
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

That makes me thinking that somehow the value of `nrZamowieniaJTF.getText()` is nothing, that's why it can't be assigned to my int variable :/

You help will be highly appreciated! Thank you for your time :)

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I my opinion there could be two possibilities:

The nrZamowieniaJTF could be not the same instance when you add it to ContentPane. So you can have different instance in ob.nrZamowieniaJTF and different instance is actually added to the ContentPane. In that case you need to be sure these are the same instances and that this field is instantiated only once, for this you should have only one invocation of nrZamowieniaJTF = new JTextField();

Second possibility is that your code tries to read and parse the value of this field before there is actually any value set to it. In this case you should parse the value from this field after it is really set.

Comment: I've double checked if the first option is possible, but I have only one initialization (the one in OknoEdycjaZamowienia).

Comment: The second option can be possible, but the value was set in another window by:
OknoEdycjaZamowienia ob = new OknoEdycjaZamowienia();
ob.nrZamowieniaJTF.setText(Integer.toString(nrZamowieniaLista));
So I just want to get the value in this window (OknoEdycjaZamowienia).

Comment: create constructor for `OknoEdycjaZamowienia` which takes `int nrZamowienia `and sets it in the field `nrZamowieniaJTF`.

Comment: Thank you soooo much, that helped me! :)